# unchecking the check box

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-java

i want to uncheck the check box iam sending value through  the json in my feature file

to uncheck the value when i send false from my json

```
  public boolean updateSectionFields( DataObject dataObject ) {
        boolean flag = false;
        FundAcceptance fundAcceptance = (FundAcceptance) dataObject;

        try {
            scrollDownVerticalUntilVisibleElement(dualDepositoryCheckBox);
                         changeCheckBoxState( dualDepositoryCheckBox, fundAcceptance.isDualDepository() );

            changeCheckBoxState( overriddenChkBox, fundAcceptance.isOverrideReason() );
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            log.info("An");
            log.error(String.valueOf(e));
        }

        return flag;
    }
```

```
protected void changeCheckBoxState(WebElement checkBoxElement, boolean desiredState){
        checkBoxElement.click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void changeCheckBoxdualDepository(WebElement checkBoxElement, boolean dualDepository) {
    if (!checkBoxElement.isSelected() && dualDepository) {
        checkBoxElement.click();
    } else if (checkBoxElement.isSelected() && !dualDepository) {
        checkBoxElement.click();
    }
}
```